# Entering numbers in Scientific Notation?

Tags: number-representation

I need to play with a lot of powers such as `10^-3`. `1E-3` does not work for it. Is there any short form for it?

Comment: Scientific notation is very convenient in programming.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I'm surprised there isn't a question about this (*i.e.* entering numbers in scientific notation) already.

To enter $3\times10^{-3}$, you can write `3*^-3`.

For further reference, see [Input Syntax: Numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#7977).

Comment: Yeah... it's indeed very surprising. Even Google does a bad job of leading to the correct syntax (of course that's before this answer became popular — now this is one of the top answers).

Comment: That notation looks SO funny and wrong to me. Where did it come from, and why not use the old E notation which many people already know?

Comment: @Ralph: Because in Mathematica `E` already means $e\approx 2.718$, so `3E-3` is interpreted as $3e-3$.

Comment: It's so easy to think of and to write `3*10^-3` that people might not be motivated to look for another way. I've seen hundreds of notebooks and only very rarely seen the `*^` notation.

Comment: The E notation works when importing data from a file with a CSV extension and in which the data values are separated by commas.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well teaching some solubility chemistry (it's logs all the way down).  The notation can get in the way, but most students can keep up with 1×10^-5 syntax - just don't forget to wrap it in brackets i.e.:

```
1*^-10/1*^-5 == (1×10^-10)/(1×10^-5)
(* True *)
```

NB: the `×` in `1×10` is added automatically when pushing space.

Comment: [A related thread.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140583)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, easy.

```
100,000 = 1*^5
1/10 = 1*^-1
6/10 = 6*^-1
3200 = 32 *^ 2
```

Try it and see!

Comment: Is the $1/6 $ an error ? That would rather be 6^-1

Comment: Sorry 6*^-1  =  6/10 = 3/5