# How do I remove the little × that shows up in the frontend when typing?

Tags: front-end, customization, input, editing

Version 11.1 now shows a little grayed out `×` (a multiplication sign) when one is editing something, to warn them that the expression will be interpreted as the multiplication of what precedes and follows the sign. However, one is still typing, and there is no need to warn one in the middle of typing before they are finished!

This is all good and well for some, but I find it very annoying and distracting when I keep seeing this `×` popup in the middle of coding. Too many things already pop-up when typing and I do not need one more thing. I am not sure what to search for in the options inspector to disable this.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Do[
  a;
  b, (*removing the , makes the x show up *)
{i,1,n}
]
```

Is there an option to remove it? Here is a small movie showing it:

[image: demonstration]

Another example:

[image: another demonstration]

Comment: "to warn them that the syntax as it stands is not valid" - rather than that, I think that's a multiplication sign, as in the front end thinks you're multiplying `b` with `{i, 1, n}`.

Comment: @J.M. sure, I understand that. But either way, I'd like not to see it if possible. Thanks.

Comment: It's going to be somewhere in the options inspector.  Search for multiplication I think

Comment: I like this indicator a lot. :)

Comment: @Kuba I agree. It would have helped me in so many ways if it was there when I started learning the Wolfram Language.

Comment: @Edmund and it is especially helpful in Code cells where the next line isn't artificially indented when it happens.

Comment: wait, why is the times symbol grayed out? what happens if the symbols `c` and `b` are replaced with integer literals?

Comment: Also, I don't think "to warn that syntax is not valid" is really correct; quite the contrary, it just warns that this will be parsed as an expression with head `Times`, so I reworded the first paragraph. Feel free to roll back if you do not like it.

Comment: I think that the warning that `Times` will be the default operator is good.  The issue I have is the following.  If the cursor is moved away from the "x" , it is very difficult to get back to that point with a mouse click.  Clicking on the "x" puts the cursor at outermost closing bracket, e.g. the end of a function.  Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to the hint by Jason. It is called `AutoMultiplicationSymbol`. It can be turned off in the Option Inspector:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It worked. Now `×` does not show up. Version 11.1 on windows 7.