# Problem with automatic times sign

Tags: front-end

I have been using Mathematica for preparing lecture notes for more than 15 years. In version 12.3 I have noted several issues with automatic insertion of times signs by the front end. Most have to do with insertion before and/or between parenthetical expressions where normal mathematical writing does not expect them. But the worst case is the insertion of a times sign between a number and a % sign. This only occurs in 2D expressions. Has anyone noticed a change here? Is there any convenient work around?

Comment: do you mean like this question?  [getting-rid-of-the-horrible-times-x-in-mathematica-12-3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256682/getting-rid-of-the-horrible-times-x-in-mathematica-12-3)  or may be this one? [how-do-i-remove-the-little-%C3%97-that-shows-up-in-the-frontend-when-typing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140583/how-do-i-remove-the-little-%C3%97-that-shows-up-in-the-frontend-when-typing)  or something else? btw, posting at least a screen shot would help.