# Remove the Times x from display in Inactivate expressions in V13

Tags: formatting, notation

I tried the solutions given in [How do I remove the little × that shows up in the frontend when typing?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140583/how-do-i-remove-the-little-%C3%97-that-shows-up-in-the-frontend-when-typing) and [Getting rid of the horrible Times x in Mathematica 12.3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256682/getting-rid-of-the-horrible-times-x-in-mathematica-12-3).

They work for standard expressions: no little `x` shows up any more. But for `Inactivate`d expressions the little `x` still shows up.  How to remove the little `x` in this case as well?

```
Sin[2*x]
Inactivate[Sin[2*x]]
```

[image: example of inactivated code in which the little x for times still appears]

it looks like `Inactivate` prevents formatting settings to be applied as well. So I need a way to override this.

Using V 13.0 on windows 10

Comment: it's really annoying! Try `Inactive[Sin][2 x]`

Comment: Yes, it works now. But this will not work for large inactivate expression when I have many things inside it. I can't really change it this way. For example `Inactivate[Integrate[Sin[2 x], x]]`  The `Sin[2*x]` was a simple example.

Comment: @Nasser Would inactivating only certain heads be an acceptable workaround? Like `Inactivate[Integrate[Sin[2 x], x], Integrate]`, which does not show the x

Comment: @MarcoB  it should really work for any Valid Mathematica input, just like outside Inactivate. ie. the little x should not show up in both cases. Now it still shows up inside Activates making it hard to read. I do not know where the * will show in generate, it can be anywhere.

Comment: and how about this? `Inactivate[Sin[2 x], Sin]` or `Inactivate[Integrate[Sin[2 x], x], Sin | Integrate]`  or `Inactivate[Integrate[Sin[2 x], x], Sin]` Happy New Year!

Comment: Or perhaps activating only multiplication: ``Activate[Inactivate[Integrate[Sin[2 x], x]], Times]``.

Comment: @Domen this looks like a good solution.

Comment: Why not? `Inactivate[Sin[2*x], Except[Times]]`?

Comment: In Mathematica `Preferences | Appearance | Formatting | Multiplication` you can select the symbol used from `{Space, Center Dot, *, x}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Method 1 – Activate `Times`

```
Activate[Inactivate[Integrate[Sin[2 x], x]], Times]
```

### Method 2 – Change the behaviour of `TagBox`

I am not completely sure this is the *right* way to change the behaviour of boxes, but it does the job.

```
Unprotect[TagBox];
TagBox["\[Times]", "InactiveToken", __] = "";
Protect[TagBox];

Inactivate[Integrate[Sin[2 x], x]]
```

[image]